# How to filter only printable characters in a file on Bash (linux) or Python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ascii

I want to make a file including non-printable characters to just only include printable characters. I think this problem is related to [ACSCII control action](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html), but I could not find a solution to do that and also could not understand meaning of `.[16D` (ASCII control action character??) in the following file.

HEXDUMP OF INPUT FILE:

```
00000000: 4845 4c4c 4f20 5448 4953 2049 5320 5448 HELLO THIS IS TH
00000010: 4520 5445 5354 1b5b 3136 4420 2020 2020 E TEST.[16D
00000020: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 201b 5b31 3644            .[16D
00000030: 2020
```

When I `cat`ed that file on `bash`, I just got: "HELLO ". I think this is because default `cat` interprets that ASCII control action, two `.[16D`s.

Why are two `.[16D` strings make `cat` FILE just to print "HELLO"?, and... how can I make that file just to include printable characters, i.e., "HELLO "?

Comment: did you try string.printable?

Comment: I wonder why the python tag....

Comment: On most *nix systems, and certainly on any GNU system, there should be a [strings](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) command.

Comment: string.printable is not working. I already tried before asking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hexdump shows that the dot in `.[16D` is actually an escape character, `\x1b`.
`Esc[`<kbd>n</kbd>`D` is an [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) to delete `n` characters. So `Esc[16D` tells the terminal to delete 16 characters, which explains the `cat` output.

There are various ways to remove ANSI escape codes from a file, either using Bash commands (eg using `sed`, as in Anubhava's answer) or Python.

However, in cases like this, it may be better to run the file through a terminal emulator to interpret any existing editing control sequences in the file, so you get the result the file's author intended after they applied those editing sequences.

One way to do that in Python is to use [pyte](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyte/0.4.9), a Python module that implements a simple VTXXX compatible terminal emulator. You can easily install it using `pip`, and here are its docs on [readthedocs](https://pyte.readthedocs.org/en/latest).

Here's a simple demo program that interprets the data given in the question. It's written for Python 2, but it's easy to adapt to Python 3. `pyte` is Unicode-aware, and its standard Stream class expects Unicode strings, but this example uses a ByteStream, so I can pass it a plain byte string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' pyte VTxxx terminal emulator demo

    Interpret a byte string containing text and ANSI / VTxxx control sequences

    Code adapted from the demo script in the pyte tutorial at
    http://pyte.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#tutorial

    Posted to http://stackoverflow.com/a/30571342/4014959 

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.06.02
'''

import pyte


#hex dump of data
#00000000  48 45 4c 4c 4f 20 54 48  49 53 20 49 53 20 54 48  |HELLO THIS IS TH|
#00000010  45 20 54 45 53 54 1b 5b  31 36 44 20 20 20 20 20  |E TEST.[16D     |
#00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 1b 5b 31 36 44  |           .[16D|
#00000030  20 20                                             |  |

data = 'HELLO THIS IS THE TEST\x1b[16D                \x1b[16D  '

#Create a default sized screen that tracks changed lines
screen = pyte.DiffScreen(80, 24)
screen.dirty.clear()
stream = pyte.ByteStream()
stream.attach(screen)
stream.feed(data)

#Get index of last line containing text
last = max(screen.dirty)

#Gather lines, stripping trailing whitespace
lines = [screen.display[i].rstrip() for i in range(last + 1)]

print '\n'.join(lines)
```

**output**

```
HELLO
```

**hex dump of output**

```
00000000  48 45 4c 4c 4f 0a                                 |HELLO.|
```

Comment: Thanks for the tag. But cat FILE to another file was just a copy of FILE which also includes non printable characters. I already tried that... Do you have another solution?..

Comment: Sorry @freddy. I should've realised that `cat` won't _really_ clean up those control sequences. I'm currently trying to find _something_ that can do that job, but I might not find the solution this evening.

Comment: @freddy: FWIW, simply getting rid of any ANSI sequences like `ESC[nD` isn't too hard, which in the example in your OP will give you `HELLO THIS IS THE TEST`. Do you want that, or do you want the plain `HELLO`?

Comment: @freddy: I've added some code that shows how to use `pyte`, a PYthon Terminal Emulator, to interpret text containing ANSI control sequences.

Answer (score 4):

for me, the following command works well, using `strings` out of box

```sh
head /dev/random | strings -ws ''
```

detail explain:

`head /dev/random` : not quite matters, just to create some lines with random chars including non printing chars that might mass your screen up.

`-w` & `-s` option of `strings`: (partial output of `man strings`)

> -w
> --include-all-whitespace
> By default tab and space characters are included in the strings that are displayed, but other whitespace characters, such a newlines and carriage returns, are not.  The -w option changes this so that all whitespace characters are considered to be part of a string.
>
> -s
> --output-separator
> By default, output strings are delimited by a new-line. This option allows you to supply any string to be used as the output record separator.  Useful with --include-all-whitespace where strings may contain new-lines  internally.

using `-w` & `-s` options, data piped through `strings` are treated as is, so `strings -ws ''` print the sequences of printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed` command to remove all non-printable characters from a file:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[^[:print:]]//g' file
```

Comment: This is correct, but beware that what is printable and what isn't depends on the locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic solution comes to my mind is

```
import string
printable_string = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, your_string)
## TODO: substitute your string in the place of "your_string"
```

If still this doesn't help then try also including uni-code specific [curses.ascii]

Answer (score 0):

See the builtin [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module.

```
import string
printable_str = filter(string.printable, string)
```