# How to stop writing to log file in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, logfile

I'm using this code to write all terminal's output to the file

```
exec > >(tee -a "${LOG_FILE}" )
exec 2> >(tee -a "${LOG_FILE}" >&2)
```

How to tell it to stop? If, for example, I don't want some output to get into log..

Thank you!

Comment: this may work (aside from telling it to stop), but do you know about the `script` utility? It may be a much easier solution to your problem. `man script`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you post as an answer?

Comment: posted as an answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what your goal is here, but here is something to try.

Do you know about the `script` utility? You can run `script myTerminalOutputFile` and any commands and output after that will be captured to `myTerminalOutputFile`. The downside is that it captures everything. You'll see funny screen control chars like `^[[5m;27j`.  So do a quick test to see if that works for you.

To finish capturing output just type `exit` and you are returned to you parent shell cmd-line.

Warning: check `man script` for details about the inherent funkyness of your particular OS's version of script. Some are better than others. `script -k myTerminalOutputFile` may work better in this case.

IHTH

Comment: thank you! It works fine but there garbage characters are really killing me.. is there any way to get rid of them?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30571263/620097 . It should help. Note that for almost any solution that deletes data, be sure to gauge your testing effort to match the seriousness of consequence if there is unexpected error. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may pipe through "sed" and then tee to log file

Comment: could you explain it better, please? Thanks )