Python 3 process non-printable characters in a unicode string
I'm reading text that contains non-printable characters such as backspaces from a file example.log.
If I'm reading the content of the file in a terminal running cat example.log, I obtain a well formatted string:
Loading file /path_to/some_db/hold_fix_crash.db
But there are some backspaces and other non printable characters in the file. When I run the command cat example.log -v (the -v option shows non printable characters), I obtain
Loading file /path_to/some_db/hold_f ^Hix_crash.db
I need to read the file in a python script, process some lines and write them back in a file. How can I process the text in these files to obtain the printed "cat" version of the string, when the backspace has been processed and is not in the string anymore ?
If possible, I'm looking for a built in solution that would process all the problematic non printable characters.
Edit to clarify:
Using with open("example.log", "r") as f: f.read() , or using subprocess.checkoutput("cat example.log") I obtain a string that contains non printable characters, meaining I obtain
Loading file /path_to/some_db/hold_f ^Hix_crash.db
So when I later run commands using this string, I have problems.
My objective is to obtain
Loading file /path_to/some_db/hold_fix_crash.db
in my string after reading the content of the file.

Are you trying to remove the non printable characters from the log file?

Depends on which non-printable characters you are trying to remove. Characters like \t, \r and \n are also "non-printable" but I believe you would like to keep most of them, don't you?

If the intent is exactly identical processing to that done by cat -v, you'll have to implement that yourself -- but it's not particularly hard to do. By contrast, there is escaping of nonprintable characters built into Python itself -- there's one implementation as part of repr(), another as part of json.dumps(), etc.

@CharlesDuffy, the intent is getting the same behavior as cat somehow, meaning I want to read a file that contains non printable characters and obtain a string that does not contain any (by processing, not removing, them). The behavior I want is identical to cat and then copy the output of the terminal.

@lord_haffi indeed, my issue is with ^H and ^[[.

Have you considered just using cat -v itself as it already exists? Your choices are that or reimplementing it (which, again, is not hard -- it's C, but I haven't met many Python programmers who can't at least stumble through reading C)

@Nesi, no, I want to process them and obtain the resulting string. For instance if I don't process the backspace but remove it, I get an extra space in my result.

In what sense is backspace not printable? If you remove backspace from a string then print that string, the output will not be as intended. Same applies to \n, \r, \t, \v etc

By the way, note that it should be cat -v filename, not cat filename -v. POSIX command line processing guidelines call for options to come before positional arguments. GNU doesn't follow this rule (and -v is a GNU extension, not part of standard cat), but a strict implementation of the standard would in your usage treat -v as a filename, not an option; see guideline 9 in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

@CharlesDuffy I edited the question to clarify what I want

My old answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30571342/4014959

Are you searching for something like re.sub(r"\b|\e", my_string)?

If you want to process the file content in the same way a terminal would, doing edits and overwrites and so forth according to cursor movements encoded as terminal control sequences, that's a much harder problem (but cat -v doesn't do anything to solve it so seems like a nonsequitur)

@PM2Ring, ...I think that question is a duplicate (and your answer there fully responsive to this question as well as that one). Its author clearly wanted only the content cat would display, so they wanted the control characters to be "processed", just as the question here does, even though their original title didn't convey that clearly.

@PM2Ring your solution was the right one. The fact that the input log mixes control characters and ansi coloring characters makes any "hand made" solution incomplete ; emulating a terminal and getting its output was the right way to go, thanks for the tip.

If you specifically want to remove backspace and yet retain the intention (i.e., the printed effect) then a trivial function to remove the offending character(s) can be done as follows:
def delbs(s):
    result = []
    for c in s:
        if c == "\b":
            # defend against more backspaces than preceding characters
            if result:
                result.pop()
        else:
            result.append(c)
    return "".join(result)

the_string = "abc\bcde"
print(len(the_string), the_string)
new_string = delbs(the_string)
print(len(new_string), new_string)

Output:
7 abcde
5 abcde

